# AWS - ElasticBeanstalk - PHP Platform - Run NPM commands

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**AIM:**

1. Wanted to run wordpress and node app on same ec2.
2. Deploying wordpress and node app, using ElasticBeanstalk.
3. Choosen ElasticBeanstalk Platform is PHP
4. I have two folders in the root folder - WordPressSite and NodeApp.
5. WordPress site is running default port as expected, as the chosen EB platform is PHP
6. NodeApp isn't running on 3000 port.

**Tried following**

1. Written commands and container commands placed them .ebextensions - which will install, node, npm and run node app
2. Check below ebextension config file.

```
commands:
    01_node_download:
        cwd: /tmp
        test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/node ] && echo "node not installed"'
        command: 'sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -'
    02_node_install:
        cwd: /tmp
        test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/node ] && echo "node not installed"'
        command: 'sudo yum -y install nodejs'
    03_create_post_dir:
        command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
        ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/npm_run_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      cd /var/app/current/NodeApp
      npm run start
container_commands:
    03_npm_install:
        cwd: /var/app/ondeck/NodeApp
        command: 'sudo npm install'
    04_npm_config_set:
        cwd: /var/app/ondeck/NodeApp
        command: 'npm config set scripts-prepend-node-path auto'
```

**Config file explanation**

1. We have written commands to install node.
2. Created a folder for post deployment execution if not exists.
3. Written files: script, which contains code to run post deployment of package, which contains npm run start (a general node app start script)
4. Container commands to install node modules and set few flags.

**Result**

1. When we do eb deploy, eb status is never ending process - because of executing "npm run start" on php platform while deploying. The deployment runs for a very long time, had to manually abort operation, no logs on why this isn't working.
2. Tried to deploy code with out the files: post deployment script, deployment works fine, all the node modules and other commands were executed with out issue. Manually ssh to ec2 and executed command "npm run start" in the node app folder, this doesn't through any error and runs the. node app on 3000.
3. When we try to run the same command through ebextensions on post deployment or command or container_commands, the eb deployment process doesn't respond for a long time - also the node app is running but elasticbeanstalk deployment isn't responding ?

So the question is can we run node app through eb commands on elasticbeanstalk php platform ?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I have moved towards - "multi container docker environment" in ElasticBeanstalk. I see that regular non docker environment in ElasticBeanstalk is platform specific (php/node), so the ebextension commands to execute multiple platforms/process weren't working properly, atleast I couldn't figure out a way seamless way, so moved ahead with "multi container docker environment"

Comment: Actually I was able to find the solution. 
In my case I was using pm2 ecosystem to start or reload my node server but the most important part was to run the command with the ec2-user like: "sudo -u ec2-user pm2 startOrReload ecosystem.config.js"